# How to pass parameter from prototypejs client to rest web service

Tags: java, javascript, rest, prototypejs

I have a rest web service like

```
@Path("/postItem")
@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
public Item postItem(@QueryParam("name") String name, @QueryParam("price") String price)
{
  System.out.println(name);
  System.out.println(price);
  return new Item(name , price);
}
```

And I use prototypejs javascript lib to invoke above rest web service from the client side with below code snippet.

```
<script>
  new Ajax.Request('/some_url', {
    method:'post',
    parameters: {name: 'apple', price: 12}
    onSuccess: function(transport) {
    var response = transport.responseText || "no response text";
    alert("Success! \n\n" + response);
    },
    onFailure: function() { alert('Something went wrong...'); }
 });
</script>
```

Problem :
I am not able to correctly pass the parameter to name and price of the service method.

I am passing two parameters in client but in service side only the parameter 'name' is getting mapped(that too with wrong value). when i print the name and price i get the following

```
 System.out.println(name);  ==> name='apple'&price=12
 System.out.println(price); == null
```

How can i pass parameter to service from  prototypejs client 
so that 'name' gets the value apple and 'price' gets the value 12.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok finally it worked by modifying the url.

```
<script>
   new Ajax.Request('/some_url?name=apple&price=12', {
   method:'post',
   onSuccess: function(transport) {
   var response = transport.responseText || "no response text";
   alert("Success! \n\n" + response);
 },
   onFailure: function() { alert('Something went wrong...'); }
});
</script>
```

Comment: But my service method is of type POST. SO I don't think this is a right way to pass the parameter.

Answer (score 0):

put quotes around "name" ie

before

```
    parameters: {name: 'apple', price: 12}
```

after

```
    parameters: {'name': 'apple', 'price': 12}
```

'name' most likely is a keyword that is not getting passed correctly in the object

**EDIT**

More things to try...

- make sure you are using the latest PrototypeJS version 1.7.1
- add a comma after  `parameters: {name:'apple',price:12},`
- double check the browser is passing the parameters correctly using Chrome Dev Tools or Firebug - if they are being passed correctly then check your back end script

Comment: Not working i tired with parameters: {'name': 'apple', 'price': 12}. <p> if i remove queryparam in service method it prints name name=apple&price=12 for name and null for price.   <p> with queryparam i get null for both name and price.

Comment: Can some body tell me what is the right way to pass query parameter to rest web service method from the prototypejs client.

Answer (score 0):

Some options you might want to try:

Pass your parameters as a JS object transformed to a query string:

```
ajaxParameters = Object.toQueryString({ qkey: qValue });
```

where qkey and qValue are strings. In your Ajax.Request's second argument which is an object, use the resulting ajaxParameters as paramter value.

A PrototypeJS Hash object also works just fine most of the time:

```
ajaxParameters = $H({ qKey0: qValue0, qKey1: qValue2 [, ...]  });
```

Whether or not the method is POST should not be a problem. Sometimes a POST method may also have an ACTION (url) with a "GET" variable like

*<strike>http:</strike>//mydomain.net/post.php?id=n&action=z*